# How to get names and scopes of directives, services and controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want something strange for our big angular project. I want to access scopes and services by name from devtool console. The simplest solution for scopes is select the DOM element and call

```
> angular.element($0).scope().books
```

in console. But it is not really usefull. So, I want to write something like this:

```
> booksPageController.books
```

and don't think about page elements.
Also, I want to access directives by name and get an array of scopes (each scope for each usage of directive) something like this:

```
> bookCard
// -> [$scope, $scope, $scope]
> bookCard[0].title
// -> "Moby Dick"
```

where bookCard is the name of directive. And then, I want to access services by name:

```
> booksService.getList()
```

It is important to get the custom services from the project. But `$http` is tasty too.

For now I found a solution for controllers:

```
(function(original) {
    angular.modules = [];
    angular.module = function() {
        if (arguments.length > 1) angular.modules.push(arguments[0]);
        return original.apply(null, arguments);
    };
})(angular.module);

angular.module('tmp').config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$controller', function ($delegate) {
        return function(constructor, locals, later, indent) {
            if (typeof constructor == "string") window.controllers[constructor] = locals.$scope;
            return $delegate(constructor, locals, later, indent);
        }
    });
});
```

This hack allow me to get the list of a controllers with their scopes. And a list of modules in a `angular.modules` that contains names of services, directives and so on.

Can anybody help my to get scopes for directives and services by names from an `angular.modules`, or decorate something to get it?..

Comment: have you tried *angular batarang*? look it up in chrome webstore or, even better, on their github [page](https://github.com/angular/batarang)